# Excel VBA Object Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba, object

I am getting an object defined error with the below code. **Any idea what could i be doing wrong?** Thanks

```
Sub Loop_Test2()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim CountAll As Integer
    Dim CountXL As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate

    CountAll = ActiveSheet.Range("A35")
    MsgBox CountAll

    For j = 1 To CountAll
      i = 1
```

This is where the error occurs:

```
      CountXL = Cells(i, j).Value
```

Continued:

```
      MsgBox CountXL

      For i = 1 To CountXL + 2
        Cells(i + 2, j) = "Row " & i & " Col " & j
      Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```

I think it is an incorrect assignment. I'm not familiar with the correct syntax.

`Error Details: "Run time error 1004. Application defined or object defined error`

Comment: Post the error please.

Comment: Hi. I modified the post after doing some test. Looks like the error is in the "CountXL" assignment.

Comment: I think it is because i am not initializing the "i". Any idea how to do it correctly? Also i think the way i am assigning the value to "CountXL" is not done correctly

Comment: just set a value to i like `i=1` . Meanwhile, please use long instead of integer to enhance your script performance.

Comment: It works fine thanks. Still getting an error when assigning Cells(i,j) to CountXL. "Type Mismatch" error. Did change to "Long" instead but i think the syntax might be incorrect?

Comment: What was the value in the Cells(i,j) ? does it belong to long type?

Comment: Cells(i,j) for example points to A2, which holds a number. This is to iterate through the rows.

Comment: Okay sorry, You are right :) I should do "i=2" to point to "A2"

Comment: @keongkenshih you should post it as an answer, and OP should accept it, if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you edit your question, you was forget to initial your `i` .So just set the value for `i`.
In future, you may use `Option Explicit` at the top of Sub to make sure you declare the variable before using it.

So for your case, just need set `i=1`, and please declare all the variables as long instead of integer. You may refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) to find out the reason why use long instead of integer.